# Renaming files by extracting parts of filenames that match with a pattern

Tags: linux, filenames, rename

I want to know which command I can use to rename files like this.

Let's say, for instance, the old filenames are:

```
0_predict-1-500.png
0_predict-2-500.png
0_predict-3-500.png
1_predict-1-500.png
1_predict-2-500.png
1_predict-3-500.png
2_predict-1-500.png
...so on...
```

What I am expecting is to extract them with the format like `{filename}_predict-{times}-{rounds}.png`, then I can replace it into another pattern, for example, `{filename}.png-result-{times}.png`.

So, the aforementioned filenames will be changed to match the pattern:

```
0.png-result-1.png
0.png-result-2.png
0.png-result-3.png
1.png-result-1.png
1.png-result-2.png
1.png-result-3.png
2.png-result-1.png
...so on...
```

Does anyone has the Linux command/tool to do thing like this?
I don't wanna write the Python script to complete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found out that there is a tool that can easily manipulate filenames in GNU/Linux which is [mmv](https://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html). It is quite much easier than the posted answers.

In my case,

```
mmv "*_predict-*-*.png" "#1.png-result-#2.png"
```

It tries to substitute each part with a wildcard pattern, consequently, we can re-use the part with `#1`, `#2`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of rename command you can edit it, I am assuming that all files are in same directory and you want to **rename all .png** files.:

```
find -name \*.png -exec sh -c 'x=$( rename -v 's/_predict/.png-result/g' $0 ) ;  rename  's/-500//g' "${x##*\./}" ;' {} \;
```

Run this command in that directory where files are.

So basically it runs two times rename command first one to remove `_predict` and second one to remove `-500`.

Here I used `x=$( rename -v 's/_predict/.png-result/g' $0 )` because after first change in the file name, I stored this new name in variable `x` and then used this value for second modification.

Command `rename  's/-500//g' "${x##*\./}" ;` is used because value of x is like `./0_predict-1-500.png renamed as ./0.png-result-1-500.png` so I just want `0.png-result-1-500.png` and `${x##*\./}` will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
$ for FN in *.png; do IFS="_-." read F P T R X <<< "$FN"; echo mv "$FN" "$F.$X-result-$T.$X"; done
mv 0_predict-1-500.png 0.png-result-1.png
mv 0_predict-2-500.png 0.png-result-2.png
mv 0_predict-3-500.png 0.png-result-3.png
mv 1_predict-1-500.png 1.png-result-1.png
mv 1_predict-2-500.png 1.png-result-2.png
mv 1_predict-3-500.png 1.png-result-3.png
mv 2_predict-1-500.png 2.png-result-1.png
```

and remove the `echo` if happy with the result. We're looping through the target files, `read` the file name components using an adapted `IFS` variable and a "here string", and then reassemble the components to form the desired final file name for the `mv` command.

Answer (score 0):

To add yet another variation, this uses the bash shell's `=~` [pattern matching operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs) in the `[[` test command to pick out the elements to be rearranged:

```
for f in ./*_predict-*-*.png
do
  [[ $f =~ ^\./([[:digit:]]+)_predict-([[:digit:]]+)-([[:digit:]]+).png ]]
  echo mv -- "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.png-result-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.png"
done
```

Remove the `echo` if the results look correct.

Answer (score 0):

Mention all the files in a file which needs to be renamed

```
awk  '{print "mv -v" " " $1 " " substr($1,1,1)".png-result-"substr($1,11,1)".png"}' filename |sh


I have mentioned -v for verbose mode

This is how it shows output for renaming

awk  '{print "mv -v" " " $1 " " substr($1,1,1)".png-result-"substr($1,11,1)".png"}' filename|sh

`0_predict-1-500.png' -> `0.png-result-1.png'
`0_predict-2-500.png' -> `0.png-result-2.png'
`0_predict-3-500.png' -> `0.png-result-3.png'
`1_predict-1-500.png' -> `1.png-result-1.png'
`1_predict-2-500.png' -> `1.png-result-2.png'
`1_predict-3-500.png' -> `1.png-result-3.png'
`2_predict-1-500.png' -> `2.png-result-1.png'
```